# Is `Range.Formula` a COM object?

Tags: excel, add-in, com-interop, excel-interop, addin-express

In other words do I need to release it with `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`?
I know `Range` is and it needs to be released but I am not sure about the `Formula`.

Answer (score 1):

In the Excel object model `Formula` is a string, not an object.

A simple test in Excel VBA:

```
Sub test()
    Dim R As Variant
    Set R = Range("A1")
    Debug.Print TypeName(R)
    Debug.Print TypeName(R.Formula)
End Sub
```

It prints:

```
Range
String
```

Comment: thank you. I guess i was confused because in the addin express the returned value type is Object and in the VBA object browser the type is Variant. Is it possible it shows as string in the VBA but gets wrapped in an Object in the inter op?

Comment: @Mr1159pm I really don't know what sort of wrapping takes place when you use interop. If dot net strings are an object in a way that VBA strings are not then you are probably right that something like that goes on, but even if so I wouldn't think that the formula property is some sort of separate object that wouldn't be garbage-collected when the parent range object is released.